# Error : Failed to find the bower component "ionic-platform-web-client"

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am running this command on node.js command prompt "ionic add ionic-platform-web-client" and getting this error....

Failed to find the bower component "ionic-platform-web-client".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.7.7)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI : 5.3.3

Gulp Version : CLI version 3.9.0

Gulp local : Local version 3.9.0

Ionic Version :  1.1.0

Ionic CLI Version :  1.7.7

Ionic App Lib Version : 0.6.3

OS : Windows 7

Node Version : v0.12.2

Tried everything  ... reinstall bower,ionic ,cordova bt still getting this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This below command solved my problem and bower install ionic-platform-web-client it

> bower install --save-dev ionic-platform-web-client

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade ionic, to version 1.2.x.

```
npm install -g ionic
ionic lib update
```

Then it will work:

```
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. Remove your `bower.json` file
2. `bower install ionic-platform-web-client`
3. `ionic add ionic-platform-web-client`