# Failed to find the bower component "ionic-platform-web-client"

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to install ionic-platform-web-client but keep getting this error..

```
Users-iMac:Beluga ryan$ ionic add ionic-platform-web-client

Failed to find the bower component "ionic-platform-web-client".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.7.10)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.10
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1.1 Build version 7B1005
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : Failed to find the bower component "ionic-platform-web-client"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386838/error-failed-to-find-the-bower-component-ionic-platform-web-client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did it for me: `bower install --save-dev ionic-platform-web-client`

The resolved issue on github is [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4468).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing bower with this command line

```
npm install -g bower
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing git for windows, make sure to enable writing the git to your PATH during the installation:
https://git-scm.com/download/win